# Error with GIT after importing changes from a server

Tags: git

I was trying to establish why a function on a website worked locally but not remotely, so my idea was to download the remote site and do a git diff in order to spot any differences.

Since I did this, however, all GIT commands are met with:

```
fatal: Unable to read current working directory
```

Have I killed my repo? is this reversible?

Comment: Usually this happens when you issue a `git` command inside a directory that does not exist anymore. Are you sure you haven't deleted/renamed your repo's directory.

Comment: how odd, the folder structure is identical, but because it has been over written (the repo exists as part of the site, not the whole) with  the remote version, I just re-CDed into the folder and it was fine. Although, my plan has ultimately failed as it is reporting changes to files that have never changed, and untracked changes to files that should be tracked!!

Comment: 'download the remote site'? I suppose that was with something non-git... like `rsync -hxDPavilyz -H --stats --delete` or `wget --nh --np --mirror`? In both cases, read carefully all the options, especially with wget re: `robots.txt`

Answer (score 18):

I've run into this problem a few times. As silly as it may sound, closing the terminal window (or SSH session) and opening a new one solves the problem.

Comment: This can happen when you perform `git checkout branch2` from inside a directory that does not exist in branch2. In such a case the problem is solved by just leaving the directory ..

Answer (score 8):

In your shell issue

```
cd "$PWD"
```

My guess is it doesn't exist/has been recreated. This happens also with dangling symlinks.

Otherwise, retreat to higher ground. Note, that depending on your shell `cd ..` will or will not work (if the shell optimizes it, knowing the CWD, it may work, otherwise you'll be catch-22: the shell cannot lookup the inode for `..` :))

Comment: That should strictly not work @crollywood since `.` is a hardlink to the old directory. It /could/ be that bash or other shells have a "smarter" behaviour since `cd` would be a builtin command

Comment: You might be right @sehe as I did indeed use bash, but nevertheless, it did work for me :)