# "git unable to read current working directory no error" - posh git (windows 10)

Tags: git, powershell, github

I receive this error: `Unable to read current working directory: No error` when I execute any git command in any directory.

To use git on powershell I installed github for windows (the GUI version) editing the powershell profile file as described here: https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Powershell

```
. (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")
. $env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1
```

This happened when yesterday I updated github desktop (I've it now at version: 3.0.9.0)

What can I do?

UPDATE:

Obviously I wasn't working in a non-existing directory. I tried to delete and re create directories but it doesn't work. Git doesn't work everywhere, also if I create a dir and execute git init in it, it won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with GIT after importing changes from a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743071/error-with-git-after-importing-changes-from-a-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this as issue in the posh-git repo on github: https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/236

And in another project where someone was having my same problem: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/473

In my opinion, Windows 10 screwed up something (symlinks?) updating itself and in order to make it works (as you can read from the second link of the issue) to refer to my documents folder (where I keep all my github repos) I don't write anymore `cd documenti` (the italian folder name) but `cd documents` and it just works.

Answer (score 11):

I have this same issue with Windows 7, and discovered a really easy solution to it. Instead of typing:

```
cd ~/My Documents
```

type instead:

```
cd ~/Documents
```

The **~/My Documents** is a symbolic link to **~/Documents** that is created automatically upon account creation, but Git has trouble with it.

An easy way to determine if Git is working correctly in your current directory is to look for the branch name in the bash prompt, like so:

```
~/Documents/someFolder (master)
$
```

If you don't see the branch name, then Git is not seeing it.

Comment: This answer worked for me.  I was in .../My Documents/... and changing to .../Documents/... solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your current working directory was removed or has changed to a nonexisting path?

Use `pwd` to check your current directory, if it doesnt exist set git to use another directory:

```
git --git-dir=/mycode/.git --work-tree=/mycode status
```

or create the directory yourself.

Comment: Read the update please! (obviously I wasn't working in a non existing directory)

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with permission on actual or intermediate folders.

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/473